# reading a "." in scheme R5RS

Tags: scheme

I need to be able to read user input in scheme for a project. For example, I need to be able to read the string `4 5 * .`. I was implementing it using the `(read)` function but it gives an error when it reads a `.`. I would use a different symbol but it is specified by the project description. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: use `(read-char)` in a loop to read characters rather than `(read)` which reads scheme expressions. And then parse the characters.

Comment: Dan, you should post this as an answer :)

Comment: Your project looks like Forth. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `read` to input arbitrary text.  The `read` procedure is only meant for inputting "S-expressions", a data format that can be used to represent a superset of Scheme source code expressions.

The reason you cannot read a `.` via the `read` procedure is that a period token has a special role in Scheme source: it is used for dotted pair notation.  `(C1 . C2)` is the way that the pair of `C1` and `C2` is written as an S-expression.  Note there is a crucial difference between the single *pair* `(C1 . C2)` and the *list* `(C1 C2)` (which is made from two pairs); and yet the only difference between the source text is the presence/absence of a single period.

The dotted pair notation is described in section [6.3.2 of the R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_378).

So, as suggested in the comments on your question by Dan D., you should consider using the `read-char` procedure to consume user input text.  It described in section [6.6.2 of the R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_614).  It may seem counter-intuitive, since `read-char` only consumes a single character while `read` consumes many characters (and builds a potentially large tree of structured data), but the reality is that you can build your own parser on top of `read-char`, by invoking it repeatedly in a loop, as suggested by Dan D.

In fact, some scheme systems implement `read` itself by making it a Scheme procedure that invokes `read-char`.  See for example [Larceny's reader source code](https://trac.ccs.neu.edu/trac/larceny/browser/trunk/larceny_src/src/Lib/Common/reader.sch#L33), where `read` will call `get-datum`, which calls `get-datum-with-source-locations`, which calls `read-char` in a number of places.

Alternatively, you might have other ways of reading input from the user.  The `read-line` procedure is quite common (and its also easy to write on top of `read-char`).  Or you might look into a Parser-Generator (like the one that generated the source code for Larceny's reader, linked above.